# Прежде всего - вводное выражение или наречное выражение?

Tags: пунктуация

Как запятнать выражение "прежде всего" в следующих предложениях? Я подозреваю, что везде надо поставить запятые, но все же...

Чем вызвана необходимость такой разработки? Прежде всего (,) введением в действие технических регламентов Таможенного союза.

В обоих регламентах есть требования к маркировке, а доказательной базой выполнения требований этих регламентов должны быть (,) прежде всего (,)межгосударственные стандарты.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае нужно смотреть контекст. Если после "введения в действие технических регламентов" и "межгосударственных стандартов" не перечисляются другие критерии, образующие последовательность, в которую можно вставить "во-вторых", "в-третьих" и т.д., а контекст исчерпывается только одним указанным критерием, то "прежде всего" не вводное и запятые не нужны.

Хотя они возможны как авторский каприз, не регламентируемый правилами, - но только в художественной литературе.

Answer (score 0):

Существует вводное слово ПРЕЖДЕ ВСЕГО (в первую очередь, во-первых) и наречие ПРЕЖДЕ ВСЕГО (в первую очередь). Семантически их различить сложно, поэтому важно учитывать место в предложении.

(1)Чем вызвана необходимость такой разработки? Прежде всего (во-первых), введением в действие технических регламентов Таможенного союза.

(2)В обоих регламентах есть требования к маркировке, а доказательной базой выполнения требований этих регламентов должны быть, прежде всего, межгосударственные стандарты.

Но: Межгосударственные стандарты прежде всего должны быть доказательной базой выполнения требований этих регламентов (нет обособления при логическом выделении).

Примеры с наречием: Но прежде всего Некрасов ценит Петербург за то, что он всегда был центром передовой мысли. Это был прежде всего и больше всего человек – в лучшем, высшем смысле этого слова.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Примеры, в которых вводное слово не связано с перечислением:

Прежде всего, мы не должны забывать того факта, что в эпоху французской революции террор был введен только тогда, когда якобинская революция уже умирала.

Это политика национального эгоизма и алчности, которая, прежде всего, саморазрушительна.

Но мы так устали от однообразия и скуки тесной судовой жизни, что нас, прежде всего, тянет на воздух, на простор.