# Прежде всего / в первую очередь — запятые

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, члены-предложения, невыделение-вводных, вводные-конструкции

`Прежде всего / в первую очередь(,) нужно сделать то.`
Если *прежде всего*/*в первую очередь* в значении *сначала*, нужны ли запятые? Кажется, что нет.

`Это(,) прежде всего / в первую очередь(,) для тех, кто...`

А если так:

`Прежде всего / в первую очередь(,) это для тех, кто...`?

И скажите, верно ли расставлены знаки препинания (в том числе и скобки) в моем вопросе?

Comment: Желательно придумать (взять из литературы) два варианта конкретных предложений, гдк вы предполагаете разное значение этих словосочетаний. Такую форму использует @Леопольд-мэтр, и она удобна для подобных тем.

Comment: What do I use? (There's a spelling mistake in your message.)

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр
Я хотела сказать, что вы выбрали хорошую форму для своих вопросов.  Вы сами составляете примеры с разной семантикой, поэтому понятна суть вопросов, отвечать на них удобно.

Comment: А что тут непонятно? Запятые расставить в трех примерах, и все

Answer (score 2, accepted):

• Тема о сочетаниях *прежде всего* и в *первую очередь* многажды рассматривалась на сайте.
[Выделять ли оборот "прежде всего" запятыми?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/443131/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8)
[Прежде всего — не вводное сочетание, но просит отделения из-за паузы](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/437172/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8B)
[Прежде всего - вводное выражение или наречное выражение?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/38792/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)
[Обособление оборота "в первую очередь"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432451/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C)

• Выводы

Розенталь ([§99. Вводные слова и словосочетания](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/47.htm), п. 2):

> ***Прежде всего** нужно говорить именно об этом* («сначала»). — ***Прежде** всего, нужно ли говорить именно об этом?* (указывается связь мыслей).

Словарь вводных слов (о сочетании "в первую очередь"):

> Редко употребляется в функции вводного со значением «возвращение к вышесказанному или предполагавшемуся» (**близко по значению к словам «итак» или «во-первых»**) **в абсолютном начале предложения** (выделено нами. — «По правилам»), интонационно выделяется: *В первую очередь, нужно ли говорить именно об этом?*; *В первую очередь, я должен написать доклад; во-вторых, отнести его руководителю и, в-третьих, договориться о времени моего выступления.*

• Постановка запятых

Однозначно не ставятся запятые только в первом предложении:
*Прежде всего (в первую очередь) нужно сделать то.*

*А что тут непонятно? Запятые расставить в трех примерах, и все* (комментарий).
В двух следующих предложениях решение принимается в зависимости от контекста, простенько не получится.

• В  помощь
[«Прежде всего» и «в первую очередь»: выделяется запятыми или нет](https://popravilam.com/blog/042-prezhde-vsego-i-v-pervuju-ochered.html) (полезная статья редакторского бюро «По правилам»)
[Алфавитный список вводных слов и выражений](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-alphabet) ("Грамота")

• Знаки в вопросе поставлены правильно, кроме одного предложения:
*Если **прежде всего/в первую очередь** в значении сначала...*
Слэш нужно отделить пробелами.

Comment: А во втором примере как знаки расставить?

Comment: *Это в первую очередь для тех, кто...* Здесь я бы не стала ставить запятые. А вот для предложения "Это(,) прежде всего(,) для тех, кто...*, повторю, нужен контекст. В качестве примера приведу цитату из С. Довлатова: *Моя жена уверена, что супружеские обязанности — это, **прежде всего,** трезвость.* Половина цитирующих пишет с запятыми, другая половина — без. А **как** задумывал сам автор — неизвестно.